# MySQL Query the most recent 10 records per different ID

Tags: mysql, rmysql

I'm trying to retrieve through a MySQL query, the last 2 records (Chronologically from our dt (date/time) column) of each  ID. There can be multiple records with same server ID. My code so far is, but not working:

```
select * from table
where sid = id
Order by dt Desc limit 2"
```

I have also tried using the ALL function however, my MySQL isn't updated enough for that, and I can't currently update it so that is not an option. I have also tried:

```
select * (partition by server_id order by dt desc) from table
limit 2;
```

What I feel like is the closest to solving this so far is this code I have generated:

```
select * from table
group by id
Order by dt Desc limit 10
;
```

This issue with this code above is its only querying 1 entry per ID now instead of 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty - use a subquery to get the rows you're interested in, and join to it:

```
select * from table join (select dt, server_id, count(*) from table
group by dt, server_id
Order by dt Desc limit 2) tops on table.server_id=tops.server_id and table.dt=tops.dt
```

Performance won't be great, but might be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: This does work for me except it is giving me 2 total records, 1 for each group. How could I get it to be n total records per each group?

Comment: Maybe something like: select server_id, dt from table join
 (select server_id, max(dt) from table join
  (select server_id, max(dt) from table group by 1) first
 on table.server_id = first.table_id where table.dt != first.dt group by 1 limit 100) second
on table.server_id = second.server_id and table.dt >= second.dt

I think you're better off with a stored procedure or multiple queries and using some outside code - this is already slow and does not scale at all.